# JSP not displaying data from POST request to Servlet

Tags: java, html, jsp, servlets

I have an index.jsp page with buttons named "refresh", "forward" and "edit". If I click on the refresh button then it call a Servlet and values are displayed on the index.jsp page.

When I click on the "forward" button it calls another servlet and goes to another page forward_call_log.jsp. In this page when I click on the "forward" button it calls another servlet and that servlet displays the index.jsp page. The index.jsp page is displayed but the values from the data base are not available.

How can i fix this problem?

**index.jsp**

```jsp
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Pager Example - www.javaworkspace.com</title>
</head>
<body>
<form method="post" action="./Problem_retrive" >
<input type="submit" value="Refresh">
</form>
<form action="./edit_call_log" method="post">
<%
ResultSet rs=null;
try
{
    rs=(ResultSet)request.getAttribute("rs");
    //request.setAttribute("rs",rs);
    if(rs.next())
    {
    %>
    <table border=1 cellspacing=1 cellpadding=1>
        <tr>
            <th>check box</th>
            <th>Problem ID</th>
            <th>user ID</th>
        </tr>
        <%
            do
            {
        %>
                <tr>
                    <td><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox"   value="<%=rs.getString(1) %>"></td>
                    <td><%=rs.getString(1) %></td>
                    <td><%=rs.getString(2) %></td>
                </tr>
        <%
            }
            while(rs.next());
        %>
    </table>
<%
    }
    else
    {
        out.println("hiiiiiiii");
    }
}
catch(Exception e)
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}
 %>

<input type="submit" name="act" value="EditCall"/>
<input type="submit" name="act" value="Forward"/>   
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

After click on the **Refresh** button call **Edit_call_servlet.java**

```java
import database.problemdesc.Problem_retrive_class;
import database.user_master.User_master;
import java.sql.*;
public class Edit_call extends HttpServlet {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)   throws ServletException, IOException 
{
    response.setContentType("text/html");
    HttpSession session = request.getSession(true);
    ResultSet rs=null;
    Problem_retrive_class prc=new Problem_retrive_class();
    int checkbox=Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("checkbox"));
    session.setAttribute("problem_id", checkbox);
    String act=request.getParameter("act");
    if(act.equals("EditCall"))
    {

        try
        {


            rs=prc.select_table(checkbox);
            RequestDispatcher rd =   request.getRequestDispatcher("edit_call_log.jsp");
            request.setAttribute("rs", rs);
            rd.forward(request, response);
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    else if(act.equals("Forward"))
    {
        System.out.println("Forward page");
        try
        {
            ResultSet rs1=null;
            User_master um=new User_master();
            rs=prc.select_table(checkbox);
            if(rs.next())
            {
                System.out.println("Value retrieve from PRC select_table");
                rs1=um.select_table(rs.getString(7));
                System.out.println("Value retrieve from PRC   select_table"+rs.getString(7));
                RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("forward_call_log.jsp");
                request.setAttribute("rs1", rs1);
                request.setAttribute("user_type", rs.getString(7));
                rd.forward(request, response);
            }
            else
            {
                RequestDispatcher rd =  request.getRequestDispatcher("index.jsp");

                rd.forward(request, response);
            }

        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {

        }
    }

}

}
```

After clicking on the **Forward** button call **Problem_retrive_servlet.java**

```java
import database.problemdesc.Problem_retrive_class;


public class Problem_retrive extends HttpServlet {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException 
{
    response.setContentType("text/html");
    PrintWriter out=response.getWriter();
    Connection con=null;
    ResultSet rs=null;
        try
        {
            Problem_retrive_class prc=new Problem_retrive_class();
            DBBean db=new DBBean();
            con=db.getDBConnection();
            rs=prc.select_table();

            RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("index.jsp");

            rd.forward(request, response);
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

}

 }
```

Comment: The problem you are describing is with a button named _Forward_ on `forward_call_log.jsp` however you have not included this code. Please define which Class and method is being triggered when this button in question is clicked?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're not attaching any data to the request object so index.jsp has nothing to display. I'm assuming this is the code that is executing when the problem occurs.

```java
public class Edit_call extends HttpServlet {

protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException 
{
    ...

    else if(act.equals("Forward"))
    {
        try
        {
            ...
            {
                ...
            }
            else
            {
                RequestDispatcher rd =  request.getRequestDispatcher("index.jsp");

                / *** YOUR PROBLEM IS HERE ***/

                rd.forward(request, response);
            }
```

**[EDIT]**

From your question I assume that the "refresh" button on your JSP works as expected (i.e. the data from the database is displayed as expected). From the following JSP code ...

```html
<form method="post" action="./Problem_retrive" >
    <input type="submit" value="Refresh">
</form>
```

the method being executed on the server is `Problem_retrive.doPost()`

Based on this we then need to understand what code is being exectued when the "forward" button is being clicked on `forward_call_log.jsp`. You have described that this "forward" button displays `index.jsp` but does not include the data from the database. Let's assume its calling `Edit_call.doPost()`*.

**I suggest you place debugger breakpoints in all of your doPost() methods to confirm this assumption, or just refer to your System.out.println() statements if you can't debug.*

Therefore you need to compare what is happening in `Problem_retrive.doPost()` to what is not happening in `Edit_call.doPost()` when no data is being displayed. I suspect that you are not calling `request.setAttribute()`

```java
rs=prc.select_table();
RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("index.jsp");
request.setAttribute("rs", rs);
rd.forward(request, response);
```

**A side note about good design**

You can read about the [MVC Design Pattern](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Computer_Science_Design_Patterns#Model-View-Controller_Pattern) for a better way of designing your code.

Comment: @Prasanta. As a side note it's considered better practise not to pass JDBC related objects to your JSP (i.e. `ResultSet`). Your controller class should extract the values that it needs from the result set and create a Collection of some kind (e.g. `ArrayList`).

Comment: Can u please explain me with an example.....As i am new in jsp-servlet....It will be very helpfull for me.........